# Button was not actually clicked but shows element.click() performed in selenium script

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pega

I'm writing an automation script for a Pega Web application. I have button click functionality, but actually the button is not getting clicked when i ran the script.When I check the logs, it shows that action was performed but it's not actually clicking the button.

I tried below actions but nothing works,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 80);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]")).click();
```

Then i tried below code,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 80);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]")));

WebElement button=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]"));

button.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Also i tried javascript as well,

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

Comment: did you try action class ?

Comment: No I didn't try that. I'll check with that as well.

Comment: @AmrutaPande, I tried with that, but i'm getting org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: exception

Comment: How are you asserting it is not clicking the button?

Comment: @rahulrai Im using cucumber to run my tests, so it goes to next test step without giving me any errors.

Comment: Can you check if manually you are clicking button any action is triggering ? Also if possible please share Link or HTML code for your page.

Comment: @cindy87 so to overcome this exception StaleElementReferenceException refresh your page and try to click it ..it should work.

Comment: @AmrutaPande i tried that, its works sometimes but not working all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue multiple times, I fix it using -

```
while(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]")).size()!=0)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]")).click();
}
```

This is just a temporary fix, I found it somewhere on Internet only. I believe it's some issue with the driver itself.

---- Edit ----

Before clicking on the button, can you make sure if the page is completely loaded(Ajax) by using below javascript commands-

```
jQuery.active ==0 && document.readyState == "complete"
```